# OpenGL depth doesn't work as expected

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, depth

I use `OpenGL` to draw some contents on the screen.

Here's the initialization :

```
glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, 10, -10);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

then I draw the objects using this :

```
void draw(...)
{
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);  //Begining the cube's drawing
    {
        glTexCoord3f(tu1, tv1, 1);  glVertex3f(offset,      _y, _z);
        glTexCoord3f(tu2, tv1, 1);  glVertex3f(offset + w,  _y, _z);
        glTexCoord3f(tu2, tv2, 1);  glVertex3f(offset + w,  _y + h,  _z);
        glTexCoord3f(tu1, tv2, 1);  glVertex3f(offset,      _y + h,  _z);
    }
    glEnd();    
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

But the depth is not respected (tested with a lot of `_z` values). It varies with the order of call, the nearer will be the last drawn.

If I draw the pink bar first :

[image]

If I draw the pink bar after the cream strip :

[image]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your problem, because I don't seem to understand your question fully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you see painter's algorithm (last object drawn appears in front), it means a problem with your depth buffer. In your case, you need to enable depth testing and writing and in your initialization ([it's off by default](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glEnable.xml)):

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

You'll also want to clear the depth buffer at the beginning of each frame (clearing the color buffer is usually a good idea as well):

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Have a look at what the OpenGL wiki has to say about [depth buffering](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Depth_Buffer).

Comment: Now, when I use `glVertex3f(x, y, z);` with differents x, y and the same z, just the first object is drawn... Any idea?

Comment: Do the objects overlap? By default an object will only appear if it is closer to the camera than the current z-buffer value. You can change this behavior to have objects at the same z-value overwrite one another using `glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL)`.

Answer (score -1):

Please keep in mind the following items which might help you:
1. The OpenGL follows the right-handed rule.
2. If you are using push and pops for handing the matrices then the last one you push is the first one that is applied while rendering.

Comment: Buddy, you should only post answer! Not "this might help you in the future".